# How to add listener certificate in DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi

If the Sign Message with X509 Certificate option is selected, a listener wants to provide an X509 certificate to DocuSign for mutual authentication. How to add this listener certificate into Docusign?

Answer (score 1):

Re:

> A listener wants to provide an X509 certificate to DocuSign for mutual authentication. How to add this listener certificate into Docusign?

Providing a cert to DocuSign for DocuSign to use for access control is not supported.

What is supported, amongst other options, is for the DocuSign Connect webhook system to *respond* to the server's (your listener) request for a client cert during the TLS handshake protocol. This is called "Mutual TLS"

To enable Mutual TLS, check the `Sign Message with X509 Certificate` option.

Doing so enables your listener to authenticate the client (DocuSign).

DocuSign will use the URL of your listener that you provide to contact your listener. DocuSign will validate your listener's SSL/TLS cert (no self-signed certs allowed) but will not use it for access control.

Comment: I have followed as you comment, But I'm getting the below error:

Comment: I don't see an error message. Please start a new question on StackOverflow.